# How to change custom value in a array using for each loop?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following array, I would like to implement a function that will loop through the array, and replaces the names.val = '', except the second item or index[1]. I tried foreach function. but i don't know how to implement it properly

```
names = [
{
  name: 'first',
  inputType: 'number',
  val: void 5
},
{
  name: 'second',
  inputType: 'number',
  val: void 2
},
{
  name: 'third',
  inputType: 'text',
  val: void 3
},

]
```

**Tried the following**

```
 resetValues() {
 let names = this.names
 names.forEach((names:any, index:number)=>{
  if(index=1){
   names[1] = names[1].val
 } else{
   names = ''
 }
})
}
```

Comment: `index=1` should be `index === 1`, and you probably want to use `names.val`. Reusing the same variable name over and over, shadowing the last, is quite confusing btw. I also don't understand, why you use a different number ever time for `void`

Comment: ... and on top you should not do anything for `index===1`, just do `names.val = ''` in case of `index !== 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to change the `val` property to an empty string using a forEach loop, for every item except index 1:

```js
let names = [
  {
    name: 'first',
    inputType: 'number',
    val: void 5
  },
  {
    name: 'second',
    inputType: 'number',
    val: void 2
  },
  {
    name: 'third',
    inputType: 'text',
    val: void 3
  }
];
console.log('Before', names);

function resetValues()
{
 names.forEach((obj, index)=>
 {
  if(index !== 1)
   {
    obj.val = '';
  } 
 });
}

resetValues();
console.log('After', names);
```